# Javascript (Appcelerator Titanium) Multidimensional Array parse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have an problem with the parsing of an multidimensional array, i get this from facebook as an answer:

In `e.result` i have this:

```
{
   "data":[
        {
         "name":"Linda Kase",
         "id":"1393034660999695"
        },
        {
         "name":"Dick Typ",
         "id":"1376046576034204"
        },
        {
         "name":"a a",
         "id":"1388801108093951"
        },
        {
         "name":"b b",
         "id":"1382328532076389"
        }
     ],
   "paging": {
        "next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.2\/1378163649155341\/friends?format=json&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     },
   "summary":{
            "total_count":8
         }
}
```

and this is my code to parse it:

```
Ti.App.fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/friends',false, 'GET', function(e){
    if(e.success){
        var result = e.result;
        alert(result.data[0].name);
    }
});
```

I always recieve this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Anyone an idea why it isn't working ? I've also tried to `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` the `e.result`

Thank you!

Comment: this one needs a jsfiddle

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(e)`? Your logic looks fine.

Comment: `{path=me/friends, success=true, result={"data":[{"name":"Linda Kase","id":"1393034660999695"},{"name":"Dick Typ","id":"1376046576034204"},{"name":"a a","id":"1388801108093951"},{"name":"b b","id":"1382328532076389"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.2\/1378163649155341\/friends?format=json&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX"},"summary":{"total_count":8}}, code=0}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use:

```
    var result = JSON.parse(e.result);
    alert(result.data[0].name);
```

because you get it as a string, not as an array